# error with searching Facebook Graph API user search

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i want to user Facebook graph api to search for user information 
but i get an Error when i write
 GET graph.facebook.com/v3.3/search?q=java&type=user

```
{
      "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported operation",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "GLFKEUeypcH"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#search lists the available search types - those are `place`, `placetopic`, and several `ad_*` searches for targeting purposes.

**You can not search for users any more.**

Comment: is there any solution to get users information rather than facebook api

Comment: Without the user’s explicit, active consent, you can get basically no info at all about them any more via API.